# Are there parallels between Ymir/Auðumbla and Paul Bunyan and Babe the Blue Ox besides the obvious?

Tags: norse, comparative, folklore

It's something I've been thinking about for many years now and I figured I might as well ask, as there seems to be an exceptional Norse mythology braintrust on this site.

---

By "obvious" parallels, I am referring to a giant with a bovine companion the color of glacial ice.

Comment: this is brilliant. I would never have made that connection.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a sense - but while Bunyan and Babe actively change the landscape, Ymir is chopped up by others (Odin & Co) to make the world. Both Bunyan and Ymir are associated with cold - PB with the "[blue winter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Bunyan)" in North Dakota, while Ymir was the first frost-giant. ([Prose Edda](http://www.sacred-texts.com/neu/pre/pre04.htm) 18)